# Why the Jerusalem Talmud is not mentioned in the Bavli?

Tags: history, talmud-bavli, talmud-yerushalmi

1. The JT was compiled some 150-200 years before the Bavli (WIKI), so the most of the disputes in the Bavli took place when the JT was already finished.
2. The Rabbis (Tannayim and Amorayim) traveled all the time from Israel to Babylon and back.
3. I don't recall any mentioning of the JT as the book in the Bavli (not the single rulings of R' Yochanan or other Israeli Rabbis).

Why is it so (or am I mistaken)?

Comment: במערבא אמרי is a reference to amorayim of erets Israel. But this isn't a reference to the book. Maybe the both Talmud were orally transmitted at the Time of the quotation

Answer (score 4):

The premise of your question may be inaccurate. The Mishnah was also a ‘book’, however, it is basically just quoted as teachings. So too the Yerushalmi, there are countless examples of parallel teachings and stories etc. in the Bavli from the Yerushalmi.

Additionally, as @[kouty said](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/95329/why-the-jerusalem-talmud-is-not-mentioned-in-the-bavli#comment314499_95329) the phrase אמרי במערבא may denote how they referenced the Jerusalem Talmud. Perhaps it is not meant to be taken literally.

Here are some references:

[Talmud Bavli, Chagigah 10a, with Rashi, d.h miTalmud l’Talmud](http://www.yerushalmionline.org):

> אמר רב כיון שיוצא אדם מדבר הלכה לדבר מקרא שוב אין לו שלום. ושמואל אמר זה הפורש מתלמוד למשנה. ורבי יוחנן אמר אפילו **מתלמוד לתלמוד**.
>   רש״י - אפילו מתלמוד לתלמוד – **מתלמוד ירושלמי** לתלמוד בבלי שהוא עמוק, כדאמרינן בסנהדרין (כד, א) במחשכים הושיבני כמתי עולם זו התלמוד של בבל.
>
> Rav said: “As soon as man goes forth from the study of Halacha to the study of Scripture he no longer has peace. And Shmuel said: “It means one who leaves Talmud for Mishnah.” And Rav Yochanan said: “Even from Talmud to Talmud.”
>   Rashi explains: “from Talmud to Talmud: from Talmud Yerushalmi to Talmud Bavli, since the former one is deeper.”

And a more indirect statement showing their awareness of the Jerusalem Talmud style of teaching on [Bava Kama 6b:](https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Kamma_6b.11)

> כשהזיק חב המזיק חב המזיק חייב המזיק מיבעי ליה אמר רב יהודה אמר רב האי תנא ירושלמי הוא דתני לישנא קלילא
>   § The mishna states: And when a component of any of these categories causes damage, the owner or generator of the component that caused damage is obligated [ḥav] to pay restitution with best-quality land. The Gemara asks: Why does the tanna of the mishna use the unusual expression: The one liable for the damage is ḥav to pay? He should have used the more standard expression for liability: The one liable for the damage is ḥayyav to pay. The Gemara explains: Rav Yehuda said that Rav said: This tanna is a Jerusalemite, who teaches using a light and concise formulation, as ḥav is more concise than ḥayyav.

Comment: I edited your post to make it easier to read. While the first citation is a slam-dunk proof, I think you’re grossly misreading the second. How can you bring a proof that the Bavli quotes the Yerushalmi when it’s referring to a Mishnah, which predates both of them? All the Gemara there means is that the Tanna who wrote the Mishnah lived in Yerushalayim, and they like being short and concise. No reference to Talmud Yerushalmi at all.

Comment: There second quotation certainly doesn't mention the JT, only an individual Israeli rabbi. Even the first probably is referring to the *study* of Israel versus that of Babylonia, rather than their *compiled books*, which latter are what were asked about here: otherwise R. Yochanan is referring to the BT many years before it existed!

Comment: @msh210 yes but then Rashi’s comments are troubling, he certainly knows the difference

Comment: @DonielF I think it’s just a reference to exactly that, how they talk in the Yerushalami

Comment: @Shmuel Read the line again: the *Tanna* is a Jerusalemite.

Comment: @DonielF yes but that fact of the matter is that whatever he was referring to carried over on a large scale to the Jerusalem Talmud

Comment: @Shmuel You have no proof of that from this particular quote. Further, the OP specifically excluded “single rulings of...other Israeli Rabbis,” so even if this is correct, it still doesn’t satisfy the conditions set by the OP. (Just to clarify once more - I’m only arguing on your BK quote, not your Chagigah quote.)

Comment: (re your comment to me) Are you referring to the Rashi you quoted? I was including that in the scope of my comment already. I think his reference to "talmud" doesn't mean what you think it means.

Comment: Thank you for an interesting try. Your examples just prove my question - there's no mentioning of the JT. So the question of WHY stays. Instead of trying to find some hints to refute it, focus on the big picture.

Comment: I don’t understand your comment @AlBerko

Comment: Your examples are so distant that it proves my premise that the JT IS NOT referred to in the BT (you did find hints, kudos!). Now my question is to explain that phenomena, as all the facts support exactly the opposite - it had to be wildly known. Can you think of a reason for that?

Comment: My example was הפורש מתלמוד לתלמוד, a clear reference to JT - what *type of reference* do you seek? Thanks @AlBerko

Comment: Nothing personal, just one word Talmud is the only indirect reference to the JT? THat's my point. Tosefta, Sifri, Safra, Mishna, Midrashim are mentioned and the JT is not? why? Many Sugiot are ruled in the JT but none is brought in the BT.

Comment: What do you mean? JT teachings are all over the bavli! @AlBerko

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel I think he means that if JT teachings *are* all over the Bavli then it should be easier to find some than to rely on such an obscure hint.

Comment: @DonieF there is virtually countless examples of paralel braiysas/teachings which are in both talmudim.