# Did Amoraim in Bavel study or know of the Talmud Yerushalmi?

Tags: history, talmud-gemara, talmud-bavli, talmud-yerushalmi, amoroim

The Talmud Yerushalmi was completed while the Amoraim in Bavel were still debating and discussing halachos that would be recorded later on the Talmud Bavli. I'd like to know if we can know or assume that after a certain point in time the Amoraim in Bavel knew the Talmud Yerushalmi?

It seems reasonable to say that if we can answer yes, then that would make a big difference in how we would approach learning the later Amoraim in the Bavli because we would assume that their conversations take the Talmud Yerushalmi into account. Or said differently, we would be able to use premises provided by the Yerushalmi to explain the later Amoraim in the Bavli.

Comment: One of the well-known opinions of the [Rif](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaac_Alfasi) is that we rule in accordance with the Bavli. Part of his reasoning is “because they (the later Babylonian sages) were better well-versed in the Yerushalmi than us.” (Eruvin, end).

Comment: Perhaps a duplicate https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/95329/16706

Comment: Identical teachings are in the bavli which are present in yerushalmi.

Comment: There were tanaim who travled back and forth

Comment: The Talmud Yerushalmi at that point was probably like any other Sefer besides Tanach at the time- unorganizef